# the server responded with a MIME type of "image/png" - HTML / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, liveserver

I'm building a mario-like game with HTML and JavaScript, and now that it is almost done, i'd like to change my rectangles (the platforms) by images.

Here is my structure :

```
- index.html
- index.js
- index.css
- /assets/platform.png
```

To import my image, in my `index.js` I did :
`import platform from './assets/platform.png'`

Browser return this error :

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/png". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I am using Live Server from VSCode.

Any help on this ?

Comment: Unless you use a special build tool that knows how to completely rewrite that code to something that _does_ work, normal, plain JS can only import other normal, plain JS (but hopefully soon, also JSON). What made you think this was going to work? Because no JS tutorial teaches you to do this, only frameworks with transpilers (like a react project) will show you code with import statements for "this isn't even remotely JS" assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use add `img` `src` attribute dynamically with js:

```js
document.querySelector('.myImg').src = 'https://placekitten.com/500/500' // or ./assets/platform.png
```

```html
<img class="myImg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Import is for importing scripts. You import image.

Comment: How can I import image ?

Comment: add <img> tag first and change src atribute

Answer (score 1):

Man, that's not that easy to solve, but i think that you are trying to reference the image with "import image from"

Don't do that, you shoul reference the image in a const., and the image source must be a url from your repository on github.

const image = new Image()
image.src = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/imagens/Platform_C.png'

Answer (score 1):

```js
const image = new Image();
image.src = './assests/platform.png'
```